# Prove Euler characteristic satisfies $\chi(X \times Y)=\chi(X)\chi(Y)$ for polyhedra $X$ and $Y$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, products, simplicial-complex

> Prove that for any topological polyhedra, $X$, $Y$, the product $X \times Y$ has the Euler characteristic  $\chi(X \times Y)=\chi(X)\chi(Y)$

I know that for polyhedron $P$ which is homemorphic to a closed surface $S$. If $P$ has $f $ faces, $ e$ edges and $ v$ vertices. Then $\chi(P)=f-e+v $.

I believe that taking the product, still makes the shape a polyhedra, but I am not sure how to count the number of edges, vertices and faces

Comment: If you have triangulations of $X$ and $Y$, there is a natural way in which you can triangulate the product.

Comment: We did triangulation earlier on in the course but I never got my head around how they work. Also, how can we triangulate for a general polyhedron?

Comment: this ans might help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614788/cartesian-product-of-compact-triangulated-spaces/1614888#1614888